# Extension object in XSLT with subclasses

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I have an extension object for my class `TranscoHelper`  that I want to call in my mappings.
 The tricky part is that I want to call methods in several subclasses of my class and not the methods in the main-class.

Unfortunately I can’t abstract the subclasses into one generic one because of the method names that are the same for several subclases.

I tried following statements but without success –

> `<xsl:value-of select="transco:SubClass1.Method1()"/>`

Did anyone accomplish this behaviour or is it just impossible?
 The less attractive solution is to add a reference in the extension object for every subclass and get rid of the main class but I’d like to avoid that if possible…

A dummy version of my class looks like the following -

```
public class TranscoHelper
{

    public class SubClass1 : TranscoBase
    {
        public static string Method1() 
        {
            return "Method1";
        }
    }


    public class SubClass2 : TranscoBase
    {       
        public static string Method1()
        {
            return "Method2";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the same answer I offered over at MSDN:

I don't think that will work because the extensions are added as instances, as much as I remember.

Instances of TranscoHelper don't automatically contain instances of Subclass1 or Subclass2.

So, you'd have to add an extension for each individual class you'd need to use.  Or, add methods to TranscoHelper that call Subclass1/2 static methods.